# Использование алгоритма Полибия для шифрования, расшифровывания файлов

Tags: шифрование

подскажите, пожалуйста, что подразумевается под шифрованием, расшифровыванием файлов методом Полибия? Понятно, как применять метод в случае ввода обычной строки и ее шифровки(расшифровки), шифровка, расшифровка файлов - имеется ввиду, что в файл записывается информация, затем она шифруется, записывается в другой файл?

Comment: под шифрованием файлов понимается что данные для шифрования программа читает предварительно из файла. куда выдавать результат - лучше уточнить, но скорее всего писать в другой файл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно в программу пишется сообщение, после чего оно кодируется и записывается в файл. Декодирование происходит при чтении файла с зашифрованным сообщением и вывода расшифрованного результата в программу. 
Такие вопросы лучше задавать вашему преподавателю, а не тут :)